# Read data from a .txt file and create an object array

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help please: I'm making a flight roster simulation in java. The roster will hold 25 passengers, 22 of which come from a text file (PassengerList.txt). For each passenger there are 3 required data points; name, seat class & seat # and 2 optional data points frequent flyer number & frequent flyer points. Each passenger is on its own line and each data point is separated by a comma. For example:

```
Allen George,Economy Class,8A,#GEO456,10000
Judy Hellman,Economy Class,8B
```

I have this class, along with constructor so far:

```
public class Passengers
{

  private String name, type, seat, flyernum;
  private int points;

  //Constructor to intialize the instance data
  Passengers(String full_name, String seat_type, String seat_number,
  String frequent_flyer_number, int frequent_flyer_points) 
  { 
    name=full_name;
    type=seat_type;
    seat=seat_number;
    flyernum=frequent_flyer_number;
    points=frequent_flyer_points;
  } //end Passengers
```

What I need to do is to read each line from the text file and create the array, i.e. make the first look line look something like this:

```
Passenger passenger1 = new Passenger ("Allen George","Economy Class","8A" 
,"#GEO456",10000)
```

Into an array like this:

```
Passenger[0] = passenger1;
```

I am obviously a java beginner, but I have been caught up on this for so long and I keep getting different error message after error message when I try something new. I have been using Scanner to read the file. The text file does not need to be overwritten, just read and scanned by the program. Only Arrays can be used as well, ArrayList is a no go. Only two files too, the Passengers class and the main method. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Why tagged with javascript?

Comment: @OldProgrammer that's my bad, I'm new here lol

Comment: I am not sure an array will work for you. Why does it need to be an array? I think you are better off making it a list of passengers. So you would read the file into a list like this: `List<Passenger> pasengers = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @magerine I just wanted to keep it simple for my sake. I can convert it back using .toArray right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as bellow :

First you need a Passenger.class. It would look something like this (Note that I have added a toString():

```
public class Passenger {

private String name, type, seat, flyernum;
private int points;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSeat() {
    return seat;
}

public void setSeat(String seat) {
    this.seat = seat;
}

public void setFlyernum(String flyernum) {
    this.flyernum = flyernum;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Passenger{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", seat='" + seat + '\'' +
            ", flyernum='" + flyernum + '\'' +
            ", points=" + points +
            '}';
}
```

}

Now for getting the passenger details from the file, I have create GetPassengerDetails.class, it handles reading in the data from the CSV file and allocating the right values for each Passenger.

```
public class GetPassengerDetails{
/** Reads the file one line at a time. Each line will is that split up and translated into a Passenger object */
public List<Passenger> getPassengersFromFile(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] passengerDetails = line.trim().split(",");
        Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
        for (int i = 0; i < passengerDetails.length; i++) {

            SetPassengerName(passengerDetails, passenger, i);

            setPassengerFlightType(passengerDetails, passenger, i);

            setPassengerSeatNumber(passengerDetails, passenger, i);

            SetPassengerFlyerNumber(passengerDetails, passenger, i);
            setPassengerPoints(passengerDetails, passenger, i);
        }

        passengers.add(passenger);

    }

    return passengers;
}

private void setPassengerPoints(String[] passengerDetails, Passenger passenger, int i) {
    if(i< passengerDetails.length && i == 4) {
        passenger.setPoints(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(passengerDetails[4])));
    }
}

private void SetPassengerFlyerNumber(String[] passengerDetails, Passenger passenger, int i) {
    if(i< passengerDetails.length && i == 3) {
        passenger.setFlyernum(String.valueOf(passengerDetails[3]));
    }
}

private void setPassengerSeatNumber(String[] passengerDetails, Passenger passenger, int i) {
    if(i< passengerDetails.length && i == 2) {
        passenger.setSeat(String.valueOf(passengerDetails[2]));
    }
}

private void setPassengerFlightType(String[] passengerDetails, Passenger passenger, int i) {
    if(i< passengerDetails.length && i == 1) {
        passenger.setType(String.valueOf(passengerDetails[1]));
    }
}

private void SetPassengerName(String[] passengerDetails, Passenger passenger, int i) {
    if(i< passengerDetails.length & i == 0) {
        passenger.setName(String.valueOf(passengerDetails[i]));
    }
}
```

}

Here is the main method to test the above code :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String fileName = "resources/passengers.csv";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    GetPassengerDetails passengerDetails = new GetPassengerDetails();

    List<Passenger> passengers = passengerDetails.getPassengersFromFile(reader);

    // For Testing Purposes lets get the Passengers

    for (Passenger passenger : passengers
            ) {
        System.out.println(passenger.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

After running the main method, this is the result that you will get :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way this can de consolidated down to two files(just the passengers class and the main method)? I’m in no shortage of thanks, the files were very clear and concise! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this main method to read data from text files and converge data into the Passengers object. The whole list of passengers in passengersList objec.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Passengers> passengersList = new ArrayList<Passengers>();
    File file = new File("Your file location..");
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String st;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] data = st.split(",");
            String flyNumber = null;
            int flyPoints = 0;
            switch (data.length){
                case 4: flyNumber = data[3];
                    break;
                case 5: flyNumber = data[3];
                    flyPoints = Integer.valueOf(data[4]);
                    break;
            }
            Passengers passenger = new Passengers(data[0], data[1], data[2], flyNumber, flyPoints);
            passengersList.add(passenger);
        }
        System.out.println(passengersList.get(0));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```